# getting 'not found' when there is a path from node A to node B

Tags: python, data-structures, graph

so my code finds a path from node A to node B, if they are connected. In my code it is returning 'not found' even though it is connected. The code should return 'not found' when there is no path from node A to node B. It does work because when you put in

```
print(find_path(web_map2, ('Node 1', 'red'), ('Node 4', 'purple')))
```

it works and it returns 'not found' because there is no path found from node 1 to node 4. However it messes up because when you put in

`print(find_path(web_map2, ('Node 3', 'yellow'), ('Node 2', 'blue')))`

it returns 'not found' but node 3 and node 2 are connected to each other.

my code:

```
def find_path(web_map, starting_place, destination):
    # creating the visited list
    been_there = dict()
    for i in web_map:
        been_there[i] = False
    # calling the helper function
    return find_path_helper(web_map, starting_place, destination, been_there, 0)

def find_path_helper(web_map, starting_place, destination, visited, cur_dist):
    # marking this node as visited
    visited[starting_place] = True
    # checking if we have reached our destination
    if starting_place == destination:
        return [destination, cur_dist]

        # if the destination is not found, visiting the surrounding nodes
    else:
        for i in web_map[starting_place]:
            if type(i) is dict:
                for j in i:
            # checking if the node i is already visited
                    if visited[j] == False:
                        L = find_path_helper(web_map, j, destination, visited, i[j])
                # add node i to the found path and return
                        if L is None or L == 'Not Found':
                            return 'Not Found'
                        return [starting_place, cur_dist] + L
            else:
            # checking if the node i is already visited
                if visited[i] == False:
                    L = find_path_helper(web_map, i, destination, visited + i[j], i[j])
                # add node i to the found path and return
                    if L is None or L == 'Not Found':
                        return 'Not Found'
                    return [starting_place, cur_dist] + L

web_map2 = {('Node 1', 'red'): [{('Node 3', 'yellow'): 13}],

           ('Node 2', 'blue'): [{('Node 3', 'yellow'): 16}],

           ('Node 3', 'yellow'): [{('Node 1', 'red'): 13 }, {('Node 2', 'blue'): 16}],
            ('Node 4', 'purple'): []}


print(find_path(web_map2, ('Node 3', 'yellow'), ('Node 2', 'blue')))
```

I have been stuck on this forever, and I have no clue how to fix it. any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You haven't shown us `find_path`.

Comment: what do you mean? find_path is a function in my code, which I put in the code section.

Comment: My mistake, I must have scrolled down and didn't notice when I cut-and-pasted.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your `visited` to a set and provided a `find_path`, and this works just fine:

```
def find_path_helper(web_map, starting_place, destination, visited, cur_dist):
    # marking this node as visited
    visited.add( starting_place )
    # checking if we have reached our destination
    if starting_place == destination:
        return [destination, cur_dist]
    # visiting the surrounding nodes
    for i in web_map[starting_place]:
        for j in i:
            # checking if the node i is already visited
            if j not in visited:
                L = find_path_helper(web_map, j, destination, visited, i[j])
                # add node i to the found path and return
                if L != 'Not Found':
                    return [starting_place, cur_dist] + L
    return 'Not Found'

def find_path(map, start, dest):
    return find_path_helper(map, start, dest, set(), 0)

web_map2 = {
    ('Node 1', 'red'): [{('Node 3', 'yellow'): 13}],
    ('Node 2', 'blue'): [{('Node 3', 'yellow'): 16}],
    ('Node 3', 'yellow'): [{('Node 1', 'red'): 13 }, {('Node 2', 'blue'): 16}],
    ('Node 4', 'purple'): []
}

print(find_path(web_map2, ('Node 1', 'red'), ('Node 2', 'blue')))
print(find_path(web_map2, ('Node 3', 'yellow'), ('Node 2', 'blue')))
```

Comment: Hey Tim! I'm sorry but I messed up my question. When I do print(find_path(web_map2, ('Node 3', 'yellow'), ('Node 2', 'blue'))) , it returns 'Not found' but Node 3 and Node 2 are connected. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: That's because you return as soon as you find ONE failed path.  The idea is that you should return only if you FIND a path, otherwise you have to test the rest.  You only return failure if you fall through the loop without a find.  I'll modify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, it's working fine for `print(find_path(web_map2, ('Node 1', 'red'), ('Node 3', 'yellow')))`:

**Output:**

```py
[('Node 1', 'red'), 0, ('Node 3', 'yellow'), 13]
```

It also works for the path from `Node 1` to `Node 2` (`print(find_path(web_map2, ('Node 1', 'red'), ('Node 2', 'blue')))`):

**Output:**

```py
[('Node 1', 'red'), 0, ('Node 3', 'yellow'), 13, ('Node 2', 'blue'), 16]
```

And also for the path from `Node 1` to `Node 4`, it returns `Not Found`.

**But** for `print(find_path(web_map2, ('Node 3', 'yellow'), ('Node 2', 'blue')))` it returns `Not found` although `Node 3` and `Node 2` are connected.

For this issue do this, add a state which does nothing and continues:
This state happens when one path from the neighbors only leads to an already visited node.

```py
def find_path_helper(web_map, starting_place, destination, visited, cur_dist):
   [...]
       # if the destination is not found, visiting the surrounding nodes
    else:
        for i in web_map[starting_place]:
            if type(i) is dict:
                for j in i:
            # checking if the node i is already visited
                    if visited[j] == False:
                        L = find_path_helper(web_map, j, destination, visited, i[j])
                # add node i to the found path and return
                        if L == 'Not changed':
                            continue
                        if L is None or L == 'Not Found':
                            return 'Not Found'
                        return [starting_place, cur_dist] + L
                    else:
                        return 'Not changed'
            else:
                [...]
```

By applying these changes, when there is no path from one node to another, it returns `None` (instead of `Not found`)

Comment: I just checked your correct. I think I confused my self when asking the question. When I do print(find_path(web_map2, ('Node 3', 'yellow'), ('Node 2', 'blue'))) , it returns 'Not found' but Node 3 and Node 2 are connected.

Comment: Yes, You're right @jeanawhale

Comment: is there a way to fix this? Node 3 and Node 2 are connected.

Comment: I'm looking for the problem, please wait @jeanawhale

Comment: Hey! did you have any luck?

Comment: I found a solution, please check it out. @jeanawhale